# Optaplanner : Which score value should I trust?

Tags: optaplanner

Which score value is the actual solution score : is it the score value returned by the method ScoreDirector.calculateScore() or the value returned by Solution.getScore()?

I'm asking this because I noticed they return different values for every new best solution found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They shouldn't. That implies you have score corruption, which is bad. Turn on:

```
<solver>
   <environmentMode>FAST_ASSERT</environmentMode>
```

and

```
<solver>
   <environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</environmentMode>
```

to find out where.